# Django - How to setup and test facebook login before going to production?

Tags: django, facebook

So I am trying to add Facebook Login to my page but I am having some difficulties. I am trying to figure out how to test these features in development before I go to production but I don't completely understand how to do that.

I have followed the facebook api instructions so I think I have something that should work but I can't test. That code is below:

```
<script>
  function fb_login() {
    FB.login( function() {}, { scope: 'email,public_profile' } );
  }

  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '************',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
  </script>
```

My App ID is correct in my application.

Here is my login button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fb_login();"><img src="../../static/textchange/facebookloginbutton.png" border="0" alt="" height="42px;"></a>
        </div>
```

I made my own so I could choose another image.

So now when I try to login I get this error:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

So I believe I have to choose another domain of some sort to test it? But I don't understand what I am supposed to choose? Do I have to start "hosting" so I can use a real domain? Can I do it locally?

I would appreciate any help in pushing me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Valid OAuth redirect URIs under Client OAuth Settings in the Facebook Developers dashboard to allow whatever URL you are using locally. Or set the site URL to use your local URL.

Answer (score 0):

your site URL should be `http://localhost:8000/`. I think the `http://` matters

```
 $scope.login = function() {
    FB.login(function(resp) {
      var args = { signed_request: resp.authResponse.signedRequest };
      $http.get('/auth/facebook/callback', args).then(function(resp) {
        // handle success
      });
    }, {scope: 'email,user_friends,user_location'});
  };
```

Comment: my bad, the http is there too.

Comment: @joe hmm...in the client oauth section is client ouath and web oauth set to yes?

Comment: Yeah both of them are. I have this error though: Client OAuth login is enabled but you haven't listed any valid OAuth redirect URIs. Click here for more information.

Comment: @joe added an example login fx

Comment: _“but you haven't listed any valid OAuth redirect URIs”_ – let me quote Pharaoh Bender, slightly paraphrased: _“Well then what do you think you should [be] doing?”_ … `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` is a field on the Settings->Advanced tab, in the `Client OAuth Settings` section. It has to contain a URI that matches the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter used in your login dialog call.

Comment: I still don't understand I have the same problem as the OP but I don't specify anything redirect_uri - its not specefied. login works in production from the App Domain, but how to get it to work in development??